# Less strict holomorphy

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Using the Grünwald-Letnikov definition of fractional derivative for complex-valued functions, can there be complex function $f(z)$ over all plane, that is not holomorphic but there is $r \in (0,1)$ s.t. $r$-th  Grünwald-Letnikov derivative of $f(z)$ exists for all $z$?